# Flutter - Record voice and upload it to firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm using `flutter_sound` to record audio and `firebase_storage` for uploading.

Recording is managed by these 2 functions:

```
  void startRecording() async {
    result = await flutterSound.startRecorder(null);
    aname = result;
    print('startRecorder: $result');

    _recorderSubscription = flutterSound.onRecorderStateChanged.listen((e) {
      if(e  != null) {
        DateTime date = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(e.currentPosition.toInt());
        String txt = DateFormat('mm:ss:SS', 'en_US').format(date);
      }
    });
  }

  void stopRecording() async {
    if(flutterSound.isRecording) result = await flutterSound.stopRecorder();
  }
```

The print statements print the following:

```
I/flutter (11507): startRecorder: /data/user/0/com.example.appx/app_flutter/null
I/flutter (11507): stopRecorder: /data/user/0/com.example.appx/app_flutter/null
```

Uploading should be done by this code:

```
  var uuid = Uuid();
  String aname = uuid.v4();
  final StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('recordings');
  final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(
    File(aname),
    StorageMetadata(
      contentType: 'audio/aac',
    ),
  );
  final StorageTaskSnapshot downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.onComplete);
  final String url = (await downloadUrl.ref.getDownloadURL());
```

but I get the following error when I try to get the URL:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleProfile'...                                
E/flutter (11507): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(download_error, The operation retry limit has been exceeded., null)
E/flutter (11507): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569)
E/flutter (11507): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321)     
E/flutter (11507): <asynchronous suspension>                                                                       
E/flutter (11507): #2      StorageReference.getDownloadURL (package:firebase_storage/src/storage_reference.dart:142)
E/flutter (11507): #3      updateUserAlert (package:electroshoex/utils.dart:58)                                    
E
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you. :)

Comment: Were you able to  resolve it ?

Comment: @Gauranga Nope.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way
initialize an instance of the audio recorder Plugin...

```
Recording _recording;
StorageReference storageReference =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('Recordings');

final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(
    File(_recording.path), StorageMetadata(contentType: 'audio/wav'));
```

Add the _recording.path as a String to the putFile method of the firebase and remember to add a content type property to the StorageMetaData lastly, it's advisable to run it on a physical device, so firebase would automatically get the current user data.